# VSCODE (MAC)でPHP CS FIXER使っている人いますか？Formatterとして機能していますか？

Tags: php, vscode

VSCODE (MAC)のEXTENSIONでPHP CS FIXER使っている人いますか？Formatterとして機能していますか？

Option + Shift + F　
を押すと
Formatting
→
Finished

と表示されるものの
何もコードが整形されません。

```
private function test(){$test = 0;
}
```

そのままです。

Comment: 拡張機能だけでなく、PHP CS Fixer 本体も導入していますか？ https://minna-systems.co.jp/blogs/vscode-php-cs-fixer-setting

Comment: 導入しています。